# CAB File on Win CE 5.0/6.0 Device

Tags: windows-ce

I want to create a CAB File which once installed on a Win CE 5.0/6.0 scanner should perform the following actions :

1. Include required files - Application executable, Database File, Data Wedge. I have all these
   files.
2. While installing the CAB File on the Scanner, the above files should be copied to the specific
   location.

The above requirements may not be complex but as a newbie I don't have much knowledge.
Can you please provide assistance here ?

Thanks,
Anurag

Comment: Read through the [MSDN walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcebx8f8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). If you still have questions, come back with something more specific.

Comment: Hi Paul,                                                          On my VS 2008, don't have "Smart Device CAB Project" in Templates Pane. Do I need to install any other version of VS or any service pack ?                                                              Also my application is built in EVC++, can I use the VS 2008 to create its CAB File ?                                                               Thanks,                                                             Anurag

Comment: Do you have the free Express Edition? You [need](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7940) at least the (non-free) Standard Edition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CAB file are very much similar to zip files on windows desktop. There are many free cab managers available online which you can use. OCP spftware WinCE cab manager is used mostly, available at this link:

http://www.ocpsoftware.com/products.php

If you have Visual Studio installed then you can also create cab files from it.

**How to create CAB file**

- The CAB manager will ask for the files and there location you want to copy it on the WinCE device.
- If you want to add or modify some registry settings on the device then you can also provide a *.reg* file in the cab manager. The registry settings will be automatically done when you install the CAB file.

A point to be noted that while generating the CAB file from the CAB manager make sure compression is not done (set to FALSE) as on the WinCE device it might not detect the CAB file as correct WinCE file.

Comment: Hi Chitresh,                                                  Thanks a lot for the response. This OCP software is a licensed software. Can you provide any pointer for any free tools ?          On my VS 2008, don't have "Smart Device CAB Project" in Templates Pane. Do I need to install any other version of VS or any service pack ?                                                              Thanks,                                                             Anurag

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same problem and did not find a good solution to produce a CAB file especially for the Windows CE 6/7 platform. So I created [a project to provide support for it](https://github.com/dilipkrish/wince-sfx). Especially without installing older versions of Visual Studio. Plus I was looking for a solution that is CI friendly.

**NOTE**: This solution does not produce a CAB file. Posting this solution incase someone else finds it useful.

This solution takes a different approach. Instead of creating a CAB file we create a self extracting zip file (exe). So once deployed on to the device once can just execute the exe to extract the contents of the produced zip file.

There are instructions in the [Readme](https://github.com/dilipkrish/wince-sfx/blob/master/README.md) to build the application and once built. Building the project produces an executable that creates a self extracting exe.

```
Sfx -an test -d <full-path-to-zip>
```

In the above example Sfx is the tool. `test` is the name of the exe

`-d <directory>` Directory to zip

`-an <artifact name>` is the name of the artifact to create (without the extension). Defaults to name of the name of the leaf input directory.

The above command produces `test.exe` that is a self extracting zip file of the directory to be zipped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for creating cab files:

http://www.mobilepackager.com/

I think it is also available for trail version but you can use it till then.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Platform Builder for CE 5.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3584) is free and has [cabwiz.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448616.aspx).